# does tensorflow take all resource from GPU, making other CUDA code slow?

Tags: python, c++, tensorflow, ctypes

**System information**

OS Platform and Distribution: Linux Ubuntu 16.04

TensorFlow version: tensorflow-gpu (1.7.0)

Python version: Python 3.5.2

CUDA/cuDNN version: CUDA 9.0 cuDNN 7

**Describe the problem**

I have a cuda lib build from C++ for post-processing after predict result by tensorflow model.
I use following way to make python able to use cuda code from C++

```
lib = ctypes.cdll.LoadLibrary(my.so)
result = lib.post_process(tensorflow_result)
```

If I test the cuda code alone without tensorflow, it work fine. (I save the result from tensorflow then use cv2.imread to feed into my cuda code)

But when tensorflow is used in my project, my cuda code become 10 times slower....
My time log is in cuda .so lib, so it's no way that the gap come from python to .so wrap.
I have try to set the fraction of GPU memory to be allocated in tensorflow by:

```
# Assume that you have 12GB of GPU memory and want to allocate ~4GB:
gpu_options = tf.GPUOptions(per_process_gpu_memory_fraction=0.333)
sess = tf.Session(config=tf.ConfigProto(gpu_options=gpu_options))
```

but useless....
so I wonder does tensorflow take all resource from GPU, making other CUDA code slow ?
the only solution is make my cuda code as a tensorflow OP by register?

Any suggestion? Thanks~~~

----------------------Update----------------------
I have tested what @AnandCU say.

```
config = tf.ConfigProto()
config.gpu_options.allow_growth = True
sess = tf.Session(config=config)
```

but it doesn't make my cuda code speed up like I test it alone without tensorflow.

Comment: use `nvidia-smi` in a loop to track your resource useage. By default TensorFlow allocated like 90 percent of the memory when it comes up, but it does not necessarily use it.

Comment: You can use `session_config.gpu_options.allow_growth = True` where `session_config` is your `ConfigProto` object . This makes tensorflow use minimum merory to start off and grow it's usage if it's available

Comment: I don't use TF, so I'm not making this an answer, but - of course it does! Why wouldn't it? Like any program doing heavy computation - with the CPU, GPU, or what-not - it uses them at the expense of other software.

Comment: Anand C U's answer is the way to deal with it. I don't know why Alexander Harnisch deleted his posted answer which also contained this technique.

Comment: Because OP already tried something similar - restricting memory usage by TF to 1/3, and by OP's account it didn't help.  The "answer" given by @einpoklum is probably "correct".  Most applications designed to run on GPUs will use up all compute resources (not necessarily memory).  This is not unique to TF.  Therefore, if you are running multiple applications on a GPU, it is often the case that the measured performance of any one of them will drop, compared to running only that one.  Again, not unique to TF.

Comment: @AnandCU  I try what you say.
'config = tf.ConfigProto()'
config.gpu_options.allow_growth = True
sess = tf.Session(config=config)
but it doesn't make my cuda code speed up like I test it alone without tensorflow